# restrict access to virtualhost

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I have 3 simple virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example1.com/public_html
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example2.com/public_html
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example1-example2-log.com/public_html
</VirtualHost>
```

Well, My Question is, how set up this:

**Example1.com** and **example2.com** can **write**, **include**, **require** to example1-example2-log
and own directory but can't write, include, require each other directories.

Comment: 1st) you have to declare `ServerName` in each VirtualHost for this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you add `ServerName` directives, you could do this, under your /var/www directory:

```
-rwxr-x---     u1:g1       /var/www/example1.com
-rwxr-x---     u2:g1       /var/www/example2.com
-rwxrwx---  httpd:httpd    /var/www/example1-example2-log.com
```

- Create a u1 user and g1 group.
- Create a u2 user and g2 group.
- Make user httpd a member of g1 and g2 groups.
- Make users u1 and u2 members of group httpd

This way:

- u1: can access example1.com (u1 is owner == rwx)
- u1: can access example1-example2-log.com completly (group httpd == rwx)
- u1: cannot access example2.com (others = ---)
- u2: can access example2.com (u2 is owner == rwx)
- u2: can access example1-example2-log.com completly (group httpd == rwx)
- u2: cannot access example1.com (others = ---)
- The httpduser can access all directories (groups g1 and g2 == r-x, group httpd = rwx)

In other terms:

- only u1 can fully access his files
- only u2 can fully access his files
- httpd can *read* all files (required since Apache needs to be able to read files to serve them to clients)
- u1 and u2 can fully access httpd's files.
- but u1 cannot access u2's files (vice-versa)